# sshpass append string to a remote file

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sshpass

I need to append a variable string, via SSHPASS (bash script), to an existing file placed in the Remote Machine.

I tried

```
echo "$test" | sshpass -p $pass $host 'cat >> /remote/full/path/log/report.log'

sshpass -p $pass $host "echo $test" >> /remote/full/path/log/report.log
```

Nothing Works

Comment: sshpass is your own bash script?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass

Comment: I think that the main issue is the positioning of the closing double quotes and so the following should work also: sshpass -p $pass $host "echo $test >> /remote/full/path/log/report.log"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out:

```
sshpass -p $pass' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $host "cd /full/path/ && echo $test >> /full/path/report.log"
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that storing a password in a script is a great security flaw, this is sshpass syntax:

```
sshpass -p 'your_pass_here' ssh user@domain 'df -h'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the 'StrictHostkeyChecking=no' option to ssh:

```
echo "$test" | sshpass -p $pass ssh - o StrictHostkeyChecking=0 $host 'cat >> /remote/full/path/log/report.log'
```

I don't know why this works, but enjoy the bash magics. lol

ASIDE:

If you set the password of the user you're sshing into as the envar $SSHPASS instead of $pass, then you can use the sshpass -e option.

```
SSHPASS=$pass
echo "$test" | sshpass -e ssh - o StrictHostkeyChecking=0 $host 'cat >> /remote/full/path/log/report.log'
```